# Select columns to keep from attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, features, delete

I have lots of feature classes that I'm working with, but the attribute tables are really messy because I got the information from different sources. So I decided to clean them up.

I made a table for every criteria one row. I want to use the table with an iterator, so all the features are imported, renamed and sorted out at once.
I added ONE column (called "Keep_it") with the name of the column that I want to keep from the old feature - all the other columns should be deleted.

It's working perfectly if I only want to keep one column from every feature, but for some of my features I want to keep two or three columns.

I tried to add a second column, but it was not working, because it was empty for most of my features. I also tried to add more than one column name in the "keep_it_2" column... also not working.

Here you can see my Table:

[image]

[image]

So for ObjectID 1 I want to keep the Field named "WSGNR" and "WSG_Name". Just keeping "WSGNR" from "keep it" works - but to combine it with a second field is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: What software are you working with?

Comment: ESRI ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots showing what you want to do?

Comment: @BERA: sure I will update the pictures in the originalpost

Comment: And what does your code look like for deleting all fields but WSGNR?

Comment: "ArcGIS 10" is several *generations* of software, spanning most of a decade. Please specify the *exact* software in use.

Comment: It's unclear whether you are trying to do this using ModelBuilder, ArcPy or some other method.  In any event if it is ModelBuilder please include a picture of a test model that illustrates where you are stuck, and if it is ArcPy then include a code snippet instead.  I think you would be best to use ArcPy cursors to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a 'cleaner' way to do it, but you could use the 'Merge' tool under Data Management>General. Just input the feature class and use the field map parameter to quickly remove fields you don't want, or to rename them, even.

Comment: I know that I can do it manually the way you described. But I'm trying to automatize the process so i can iterate over all my input data.

Comment: Oh, I missed the part where you wanted to keep specific columns on a per-feature basis.

Answer (score 0):

I just find this to be easier to do with GDAL using `ogr2ogr` - just do a regular SQL Query in the `SELECT` statement you list the columns you want to keep and you can alias columns as well as changing order.

Here is an example.

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -skipfailures -progress -sql "SELECT BDRY_IDENT as IDENT,TYPE,NAME,CLASS FROM boundary_airspace_highandlow_merged WHERE TYPE IN ('11','8') AND CLASS='C'" %process_dir%\class_c_airspace_forlinelimitedattributes.geojson %process_dir%\boundary_airspace_highandlow_merged.shp
```

Easiest way to install GDAL is via OSGEO4W Installer and it will install most utilities and QGIS Desktop.